# element location different when load/refresh and refresh ignoring cache in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, styling

Location of element is different when loading/refresh page(enter url or go with link refresh) and refresh ignoring cache (ctrl+shift+r) in Firefox. Its all right in all other browsers(shows like second pic). What can be a cause?

- Here is my search when entered url in browser.
  [image]
- Here is the same page but when reloaded(refresh)
  [image]
- Here is my code.

  ```
  <div class="my-search-box">
  <span style="position: relative">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search..." 
                name="s" class="tm-input"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
  </span>
  </div>
  ```
- CSS

  ```
  form input {
    width: 225px;
    height: 27px;
    padding: 5px 10px;

    position: relative; 
    right: 0px;           
  }

  .my-search-box{
      position: relative; 
      padding: 5px; 
      display: box;
      overflow: hidden;'
  }

  .my-search-box a{   
      position: absolute; 
      right: 5px; 
      padding: 2px 10px; 
      z-index: 2; 
      border-left: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  }

  .my-search-box a i {
      width: 13px;
  }
  ```

Comment: need more description of your problem , i am not able to understand

Comment: If you can give some fiddle, would be fine.

Comment: Set margin and outline of page (html/body) to 0px then keep us updated.

Comment: It seams like its firefox cache problem. It shows right when ctrl+shift+r all other way shows like first pic in firefox. I know that firefox cashing system is some strange but why will css change? Both way should be same because new loaded css and cashed css are same.

Comment: @Tooraj it doesn't work

Comment: @Manjunath my problem is in pic 1 and pic 2, they are different when "loaded/refreshed" and "refreshed with cache". I want the second way and all other browsers work that way.

Comment: Could you give a reason for downvoting? Just to know what am I doing wrong? if its about research, I'm searching for answer for 4 hours min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with replacing span with div and adding display:inline-block css to it.

I don't know what was the exact problem. Maybe it was about height of span? Would like to know what was the cause anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Updated FIDDLE - `working in chrome and firefox not checked in IE`

http://jsfiddle.net/g3412syo/7/

```
form input {
  width: 225px;
  height: 27px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative; 
  right: 0px;           
}

.my-search-box{
    position: relative; 
    padding: 5px; 
    display: box;
    overflow: hidden;'
}

.my-search-box a{   
    position: absolute; 
    right: 5px; 
    top:0;//new changes
    padding: 10px 10px; //changed padding
    z-index:20; //changed
    border-left: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.my-search-box a i {
    width: 13px;
}
```

Comment: It was little part of my project and my project contains many other library and css files. Because of that I couldn't create all of them. But when I create that part only, there is no problem on jsfiddle. Thanks anyway for answer